# using method as function in python

Tags: python, function, methods

Say I have a list of strings, and I want to filter out all non-upper case strings. Is there a simpler way than doing filter(lambda x: x.isupper(), list)?

Comment: @The Communist Duck: why is boilerplate bad? It's not a big deal, but it is annoying.

Comment: You could define a function to do this, but it will still take one line to invoke it.

Comment: @CromTheDestroyer: What part is "boilerplate"?  Can you be more specific on what you object to?

Comment: @S.Lott: the lambda is. In my head I was contrasting it to the case where a function is passed in. Cosmologicon's answer is what I was looking for.

Comment: @CromTheDestroyer: The `lambda` is as much boilerplate as the word `filter`.  Only in the most trivial of cases could is be considered "boilerplate".  `lambda x: x.isupper() and x not in ('Z','z')` would demonstrate that the `lambda` is essential syntax.

Comment: @S.Lott: the lambda is essential syntax in the example you gave because in that case we're defining a wholly different function from "isupper". In the example I gave, I just wanted "isupper", so all the lambda was doing was wrapping that. Wrapping a function and doing _absolutely nothing else_ is, IMO, boilerplate. Fortunately, it's not necessary, as the accepted answer shows.

Comment: @CromTheDestroyer: Wrapping a function and doing absolutely nothing else isn't "boilerplate".  It's a total waste of syntax.

Comment: @CromTheDestroyer:  It's not worse.  It's completely different.  "Useless" != "Boilerplate".  Your comments about "boilerplate" are confusing, since you actually appear to be talking about "useless".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I would prefer a list comprehension, this seems to be what you're looking for:

```
filter(str.isupper, list)
```

Comment: If the function already works as-is, why bother with the comprehension?

Comment: You're right, this is a perfectly fine use of filter. I hardly ever use it is all. I just like comprehensions.

Comment: Clearly you're using `list` as a metasyntactic variable here, but if you weren't, I would have to point out that using `list` this way masks a built-in ;).

Answer (score 5):

```
uppers = [s for s in list if s.isupper()]
```

Comment: I think this would be easier to read with `s` as the variable name instead of `i`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified that the question was about passing methods into functions as functions, not solving this trivial problem.

Comment: ok, no problem. (if you re-read your question you will see that it's nearly impossible to understand that).